# How to echo a string of html from one page to another in PHP

Tags: php, html, authentication, web, server

For instance, when the user submits a form, code from another .php file is executed and then the focus comes back to the previous page (the one with the form on it). Is it possible to send markup back to the first page from the .php file that handles the action?

I would like to send a message back to the user if there was a problem with their login, preferably without using JavaScript.

I'm assuming there's a simple solution for this that doesn't require assigning a string to $_SESSION, and then printing that on the other page, but I can't think of one.

Comment: using the $_SESSION is the best way,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this.

form.php post a value to calc.php

calc.php redirect user to form.php with the input value and the output value

form.php

```
if(isset($_GET['output_value'])){
    $input_value = $_GET['input_value'];    // get back some value from calc.php
    $output_value = $_GET['output_value'];  // get back some value from calc.php
    echo "Input value: " . $input_value . "<br>";
    echo "Output value: " . $output_value. "<br>";
}
```

calc.php

```
$input_value = $_POST['input_value'];
$output_value = $input_value * $input_value;
header("Location: http://www.example.com/form.php?input_value=" . $input_value . "&output_value=" . $output_value); // redirect user to the first page with some values
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Didn't realise you could append to the URL and use GET to extract that data on the other page. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is handled with html attribute in tags or with javascript but they are not secure and can be edited best way is handled with all of them

**Example :**

```html
// For Not Null
<input name="test" require> 

// Minimum Value Must Be Bigger Than 5 or equal 5
<input name="test" min="5"> 

// Maximum Value Must Be lowee Than 5 or equal 5
<input name="test" max="5">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

After this form submitted check it into php